# Reading radio buttons from module in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i have created this module and i know that the student and teacher in the structure student and teacher are put as string (these are stored as my radio buttons), but when i save these to the file, this works by saving a true or false value for the id and password. however, i am unable to read the radio buttons from another class.

this is my module class

```
Imports System.IO
Module user_info_mod
    Structure user
        <VBFixedString(3)> Dim name As String
        <VBFixedString(3)> Dim password As String
        <VBFixedString(7)> Dim student As String
        <VBFixedString(3)> Dim teacher As String
    End Structure
    Public newuser As user
    Public userNumber As Integer = FreeFile()
    Public userrecordNumber As Integer = 1
    Public Sub setRecordNumber()
        Dim n As Byte = 0
        FileOpen(userNumber, "D:\users.dat", OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.Read)
        While Not EOF(userNumber)
            n = n + 1               'increments the record number of the user
            FileGet(userNumber, newuser, n)
        End While
        userrecordNumber = n
        FileClose(userNumber)
    End Sub

End Module
```

this is where i am trying to read the radio button in the main file (        newuser.student=True)

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)         Handles cmdLogin.Click
        Dim password As String
        password = txtPassword.Text
        Dim username As String
        username = txtUsername.Text
        FileOpen(userNumber, "D:\users.dat", OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.Read)
        FileGet(userNumber, newuser, userrecordNumber)

        If password = newuser.password And username = newuser.name And newuser.student = True Then
            MsgBox("ID Accepted")

            Dim frmNew As New Student_selection    
            frmNew.ShowDialog() 
            FileClose(userNumber)

        Else
            FileClose(userNumber)
            MsgBox("ID is not accepted")
        End If
    End Sub
```

if i am to change the string to boolean in the module, this is not enabling me to save a user's file when setting the record number within the module, so what is the correct way in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem has been solved. The order of the radio buttons within the module had to be changed first, and then changed to a Boolean.    `Dim student As Boolean`